# Getting all role permissions as list

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to get all role permissions as list, but using `...roles.cache.get("910908545124413500").permissions` leads me to this result: `Permissions { bitfield: 104320585 }` and `...roles.cache.get("910908545124413500").permissions.toString()` returns `[object Object]`!

What can I use to get all roles perms as list (without using `permissions.has()` for each permission)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took me some time to look through the documentation but found that the method [`toArray()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=toArray) returns an array of strings with the permissions.

```js
...roles.cache.get("123456789").permissions.toArray()
```